# JS not redirecting page

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery Code:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("pet_name") === ''){
    alert("empty");
    window.Location.replace("<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Lost");
}
```

This code is inside document ready function. if condition is executed but still it not redirecting page. Can anyone help me why it not redirecting page?

Comment: `Location vs location`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this as an answer, although @ANS deserves the credit: it's `location` (all lowercase), not `Location`. This might be confusing from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace#Syntax) since the object is called "Location", but if you look at the usage examples you'll see that the property on the `window` is all lowercase:

`window.location.replace("<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Lost");`